# How to handle end of time series in pandas resample when upsampling?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, date-range, resampling

I want to resample from hours to half-hours. I use `.ffill()` in the example, but I've tested `.asfreq()` as an intermediate step too.

The goal is to get intervals of half hours where the hourly values are spread among the upsampled intervals, and I'm trying to find a general solution for any ranges with the same problem.

```
import pandas as pd

index = pd.date_range('2018-10-10 00:00', '2018-10-10 02:00', freq='H')
hourly = pd.Series(range(10, len(index)+10), index=index)
half_hourly = hourly.resample('30min').ffill() / 2
```

The `hourly` series looks like:

```
2018-10-10 00:00:00    10
2018-10-10 01:00:00    11
2018-10-10 02:00:00    12
Freq: H, dtype: int64
```

And the `half_hourly`:

```
2018-10-10 00:00:00    5.0
2018-10-10 00:30:00    5.0
2018-10-10 01:00:00    5.5
2018-10-10 01:30:00    5.5
2018-10-10 02:00:00    6.0
Freq: 30T, dtype: float64
```

**The problem** with the last one is that there is no row for representing `02:30:00`

I want to achieve something that is:

```
2018-10-10 00:00:00    5.0
2018-10-10 00:30:00    5.0
2018-10-10 01:00:00    5.5
2018-10-10 01:30:00    5.5
2018-10-10 02:00:00    6.0
2018-10-10 02:30:00    6.0
Freq: 30T, dtype: float64
```

I understand that the `hourly` series ends at 02:00, so there is no reason to expect pandas to insert the last half hour by default. However, after reading a lot of deprecated/old posts, some newer ones, the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), and [cookbook](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#resampling), I still weren't able to find a straight-forward solution.

Lastly, I've also tested the use of `.mean()`, but that didn't fill the NaNs`. And interpolate()` didn't average by hour as I wanted it to.

My `.ffill() / 2` almost works as a way to spread hour to half hours in this case, but it seems like a hack to a problem that I expect pandas already provides a better solution to.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your precise issue can be solved like this

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> index = pd.date_range('2018-10-10 00:00', '2018-10-10 02:00', freq='H')
>>> hourly = pd.Series(range(10, len(index)+10), index=index)
>>> hourly.reindex(index.union(index.shift(freq='30min'))).ffill() / 2
2018-10-10 00:00:00    5.0
2018-10-10 00:30:00    5.0
2018-10-10 01:00:00    5.5
2018-10-10 01:30:00    5.5
2018-10-10 02:00:00    6.0
2018-10-10 02:30:00    6.0
Freq: 30T, dtype: float64

>>> import pandas as pd
>>> index = pd.date_range('2018-10-10 00:00', '2018-10-10 02:00', freq='H')
>>> hourly = pd.Series(range(10, len(index)+10), index=index)
>>> hourly.reindex(index.union(index.shift(freq='30min'))).ffill() / 2
```

I suspect that this is a minimal example so I will try to generically solve as well. Lets say you have multiple points to fill in each day

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> x = pd.Series([1.5, 2.5], pd.DatetimeIndex(['2018-09-21', '2018-09-22']))
>>> x.resample('6h').ffill()
2018-09-21 00:00:00    1.5
2018-09-21 06:00:00    1.5
2018-09-21 12:00:00    1.5
2018-09-21 18:00:00    1.5
2018-09-22 00:00:00    2.5
Freq: 6H, dtype: float64
```

Employ a similar trick to include 6am, 12pm, 6pm on 2018-09-22 as well.

Re-index with a shift equal to that you want to have as an inclusive endpoint. In this case our shift is an extra day

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> x = pd.Series([1.5, 2.5], pd.DatetimeIndex(['2018-09-21', '2018-09-22']))
>>> res = x.reindex(x.index.union(x.index.shift(freq='1D'))).resample('6h').ffill()
>>> res[:res.last_valid_index()]  # drop the start of next day
2018-09-21 00:00:00    1.5
2018-09-21 06:00:00    1.5
2018-09-21 12:00:00    1.5
2018-09-21 18:00:00    1.5
2018-09-22 00:00:00    2.5
2018-09-22 06:00:00    2.5
2018-09-22 12:00:00    2.5
2018-09-22 18:00:00    2.5
Freq: 6H, dtype: float64
```